# How to make background be oval on my button

Tags: html, css, hover

I want my button to have a shape like it has on stack overflow Products button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxnJ7.png)

I tried border radius but it wasn't big enough. I tried to search for another options but I didn't found any or didn't understand.
This is my CSS

```
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
  color: #1b1b32;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 40%;
}
li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.2%;
  margin: 0.7%;
```

[What I got from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlszq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `padding` and `border-radius` as shown below and remove border radius which you have given on `:hover`

```
nav > ul > li {
      border-radius: 50px;
      padding: 10px 15px;
    }
```